# Socket.io Error: failed to require "socket.io" from "root"

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

The serverside part of socket.io works, but if I try to run the client-side example script [from here](http://socket.io/#home) then I get an error: `Error: failed to require "socket.io" from "root"`

I downloaded the clientside library too: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client 
I have no idea what the error is. I hope somebody knows the answer.

Thanks is advance,

Comment: Please post your server-side and client-side code.

Comment: The same as in the website's client-server example: http://socket.io/

Comment: Hi I just upgraded from 0.9 to 1.0.0, this is the development branch right now and I think there is a bug in that version. I found this PullRequest here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/520 if you just need a version of socket.io I would go for 0.9. Just use "npm install socket.io to install it."

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just made the same mistake you did, and came across the answer. Apparently, you don't actually need to separately download socket.io-client.js. By including the client-side script yourself, you are preventing it from accessing the rest of the resources it needs in the root directory, which is throwing the error you saw.

The trick is that when you run the server-side module, it exposes the file "/socket.io/socket.io" for the front-end. So regardless of how your static router is configured, just include that path like so:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```